# wpa_supplicant - how to switch to different network?

Tags: python, linux, unix, archlinux, wpa-supplicant

**What I need:**
Connect to different wifi network on archlinux by calling python script.

**What I am doing:**
Executing the following statements from python:

```
wpa_passphrase "MySSID" "MyPass"> /etc/wpa_supplicant/profile.conf
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/profile.conf
dhcpd wlan0
```

It works only for the first attempt. When it is executed the second time, it says dhcpd is already on.
I dont know how to switch to another network.

I have also tried wpa_cli and again, dont know how to switch to another network.

Please suggest some fix or alternatives (uncomplicated)

Comment: A poor mans solution is simply to perform `killall` on `wpa_supplicant` and wait a second or two until it exits.

Comment: use dhcp , down interface, reuse dhcp. How to clear interface currient settings ?

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer to this, [this post may be helpful](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136971/83790). It uses multiple network definitions in `wpa_supplicant`, and then uses `wpa_cli` to 1) shuffle `priorities` & 2) `reassociate` to connect to the highest priority network.

Answer (score 3):

Your concrete Problem is that you start wpa_supplicant and dhcp instead of re-starting them. I have a script that reads

```
#shutdown dhc
dhclient -r
#shutdown wpa_supplicant
killall wpa_supplicant
#down interface
ifdown --force wlan0
sleep 1
#your wpa startup here:
wpa_supplicant -t -fYOUR_LOG_FILE -cYOUR_wpa_supplicant.conf -B -iwlan0
sleep 1
#restart dhc
dhclient -nw
```

I guess you can do this a little more nicely by configuring your /etc/network/interfaces appropriately.

Btw. in principle, it should not be necessary to restart the dhc at all. After some while it should realize that it needs to fetch a new IP, but for me this takes to long. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Complete the file to make it look like that (replacing wifi_name and wifi_key by their real values of course).

```
network={
         ssid="wifi_name1"
         psk="wifi_key1"
}
```

and

```
network={
         ssid="wifi_name2"
         psk="wifi_key2"
}
```

Then  save and exit

The wifi network is now configured, we must now tell that we want to connect to it using this configuration file.

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c <(wpa_passphrase MYSSID passphrase)
```

If your interface isn't named wlan0 then replace wlan0 by the real name of your interface.
We must now request an IP adress.

```
dhclient wlan0
```

If everything gone well you now see several lines containing some IP addresses and the command ping should work.

Comment: dude, thats what the commands I posted do. I need to know how to switch to another network once this has been done.

Answer (score -1):

When you generate a new config with `wpa_passphrase`, put it in a different spot than the last to make things easier. So for example, your home wifi could be in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/home.conf` and your work wifi could be in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/work.conf`.

Then when you need to connect to your home wifi you just run

```
killall wpa_supplicant # With root privileges
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/home.conf
```

And when you need to connect to your work wifi you run

```
killall wpa_supplicant # With root privileges
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/work.conf
```

Rince and repeat for any new networks you want to use. If you don't want to keep a network, like a starbucks wifi on a roadtrip, just save it to a conf that you plan on overwriting or deleting like `/etc/wpa_supplicant/temp.conf`.

AFAIK, you never have to rerun dhcpcd. I have dhcpcd as a startup process and whenever I switch wifis I never need to touch it.

Edit: You also don't need to run this as a python script. You can do it in the shell. If you need to write a script that quickly changes the wifi, I would recommend you use a shell script like the following for example.

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$1" ] && exit 1
[ ! -f "/etc/wpa_supplicant/${1}.conf" ] && echo "$1 is not a wpa_supplicant config file" && exit 1
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c "/etc/wpa_supplicant/${1}.conf"
```

Run like

```
wifichange home
```

or

```
wifichange work
```

The `[ -z "$1" ]` section is saying to quit if you didn't input anything. (like)

```
wifichange
```

And the `[ ! -f ...]` section is saying to quit if you didn't input the name of a real config file.

Now I tested the script.